# Can I use patent US6610337 abroad?

Tags: international, us6610337

Is it for all of the world or only for USA? What kind of troubles can I face in case if I start business related to this patent in another country?

Answer (score 1):

This patent is US issued which means it covers the US only. However, the inventor may have also patented it in other countries which would then cover their respective territories. In addition, there may be child or parent applications which may have been issued separate patents:

> 10/650,912 filed on 08-28-2003 which is Abandoned claims the benefit of 10/334,827

This particular US patent seems to have expired:

> Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362; 09-26-2011

In some cases the inventor can pay the fees and get it resurrected again.